# Where did preview and formatting controls go?

Tags: bug, user-interface, markdown-preview, captcha

Every once in a while I want to post a question or an answer and the controls are missing and the preview area never populates.  In fact, this is happening to me with *this* question right now.  Here's a screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

If I submit a post when this happens, I get the "Human Verification" dialog with a captcha; normally I don't get that.

Reloading the page doesn't fix the problem.  What causes this and how can I fix it?

**Addendum**: Loading the initial article page ([Is this rule for graph isomorphism true?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/950248/is-this-rule-for-graph-isomorphism-true/950257#950257) in this case) produces the following diagnostics on the JS console:

```
* The connection to wss://qa.sockets.stackexchange.com/ was interrupted while the page was loading. full.en.js:1
"soup injecting fixes" SOUP.user.js:1158
"soup init complete" 950257:29
"soup setup complete" 950257:29
"soup mathjax config loading" 950257:29
"soup adding vote event handler for mse115702" 950257:29
"soup JS fixes applied" 950257:29
* no element found a930:1
* TypeError: SE.mathjaxEditingNew is undefined mathjaxMSEincremental.user.js:773
Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated.  Use defaultPrevented instead.
```

Items with stars are errors.

On the other hand, [this page](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16918/where-did-preview-and-formatting-controls-go) shows the same problem for me just now, and the console doesn't show any of those errors, so I'm not sure the errors are related.

**Added 20141010**: The problem was caused by an obsolete GreaseMonkey script. This bug report can be closed.

Comment: Any errors in the Javascript console? The symptoms are consistent with WMD or related script failing to load.

Comment: That's a good idea, thanks.  I'll take a look next time the problem recurs.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a localized problem caused by a userscript.

Comment: I agree. I have voted to close it.  Admins should change the tag to `wontfix` or whatever is appropriate.

Comment: Or you could just delete it, saving others a few clicks...

Comment: I'm leaving it, in case someone else searches for those error messages.